# BroadcastReceiver - listenting to "soon to happen" events

Tags: android, calendar, broadcastreceiver

I'm building and Android app for sdk 14 and up so there is a native calendar app. I'm trying to build a BroadCastReceiver that listens to a "this event will start soon" (reminder?) type of event. I went through [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) but could not find any info.

Can anyone tell me where I can read on the different type of events that I can listen to for the calendar. Thanks :)

Comment: There is no such thing. You'll have to query the calendar, determine what events are happening "soon" and then set yourself an alarm.

Comment: I see, thank you. So I would set an alarm using the AlarmManager? But I can listen to calendar changed events, right?

Comment: Yes and yes. You can.